# Rigging multiple bones to an object shaped for it: How?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

Off-topic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4i5pm.jpg

...Good to know.

On-topic:

I am trying to model (and rig) wings. The problem is that, when I used cylinders, 5 cylinders, duplicated, to represent the skeleton, then add bones to it, I got an error. (I am not sure if I asked this before, I may have forgotten.)

Even worse, I believe part of the cause is that the cylinders were joined, as there were *no* problems when they were not joined, as I had later checked.

...Is there *any* way to sculpt or mesh some wings (I will cover the Soft Bodies and clothes later) with multiple bones without it giving me an error? I just want to make it look realistic, which requires it joining, and I am not sure if I will have to resort to Shape Keys.

Comment: I think posting a blend file may be helpful. It's hard to follow what you're asking.

Comment: "An error". Look in the Console, what error message?

Comment: "Bone Heat Weighting"

It tells us that it failed to work for 1 or more bones. Now, I have seen this complaint in plenty of questions across the site, but for this issue in particular, we are dealing with 5 bones, all extruded from the base, trying to be rigged onto a mesh resembling the bones for wings. Using separate bones failed, too. I have no idea what to do.